# HTML Anchor Tag Not Working in Outlook

Tags: html, outlook, html-email, anchor

I am making email template in Django to be sent to Outlook and I want to add anchor tag for navigation. However, I found the tags work in html browser but not in Outlook (both 2010 and 2013). Could anyone advise what have gone wrong and how to fix it? Many thanks.

Specifically I want the screen will move to Text1 location by clicking Text in the outlook:

```
<table><tr><td>
<p><a href="#body204" style="text-decoration:none; color:#0000FF;"> Text </a></p>
</td></tr></table> 

<table><tr>
<td name="body204"> Text1</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: This question in it's current form isn't going to get you anyway. Leave out anything about django. Django really has nothing at all to do with this problem. It's the HTML rendering capabilities of outlook that you need to be concerned with. So instead of the template post your HTML

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I revised the question in hope of being advised more easily.

Comment: remove the django tag and django template. The peopl you want looking at this are outlook experts they are unlikely to know django so they will keep away

Comment: done, then do you have any advice on that?

Answer (score 1):

I think I can answer my question with a solution. The key is the tag holding the href anchor has to be the same as the one the href is pointing to. Specifically:

```
<table><tr><td>
<p><a href="#body204" style="text-decoration:none; color:#0000FF;"> Text </a></p>
</td></tr></table> 

<table><tr>
<td> <a name="body204"> Text1</a></td>
</tr></table>
```

Hope this helps those struggling with the outlook in anchor tagging.

Answer (score 1):

This will work in outlook: `<a name="body204"></a>` - take the anchor tag and inject it inside (empty value will work).

```html
<table><tr><td>
<p><a href="#body204" style="text-decoration:none; color:#0000FF;"> Text </a></p>
</td></tr></table> 

<table><tr>
<td ><a name="body204"></a> Text1</td>
</tr></table>
```